# I got an example of sentence which may be corrected

Tags: grammar

> I got a sentence **says** " I'm a catfish "

or

> I got a sentence **saying** " I'm a catfish "

or you have the right example for that?

Comment: We have no context to go on. Either could be 'correct' for a given definition of 'correct'. The first could be an extremely colloquial version of "I'm going to catch fish". The second is a simple statement of what type of fish I am.

Comment: My question is so simple which one is the correct sentence, Either I got a sentence says or I got a sentence saying, just neglect the catchfish

Comment: It is not at all apparent from your post what you actually appear to be asking. However, both are still highly dependant on context. You need to edit your post & clarify. My vote to close as 'unclear' still stands.

Answer (score 1):

> I got a sentence saying "I'm a catfish."

Without context, I'll assume you mean *got* as in *received* the sentence, perhaps on a piece of paper.  In that case, this is correct.

If you mean only that you *possess* the sentence, you'd say "I *have* a sentence saying 'I'm a catfish.'"

> I got a sentence says "I'm a catfish."

This is colloquial.  You can hear it in spoken English:

> "I can race to that tree and back in ten seconds."
>
> "Oh yeah?  I *got* ten bucks *says* you can't."

The second character is proposing a bet, or wager.  Both *got* and *says* in this sentence are colloquial uses.  They wouldn't be correct in written English unless you're representing a character's dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is correct

> I got a sentence **saying** "I'm a catfish"

but

> I ***have** a sentence saying "I'm a catfish".

would be better.

Your first example should be

> I ***have*** a sentence ***that*** says "I'm a catfish".